# Как сделать пагинацию в PyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать пагинацию в PyTelegramBotAPI
Например, у меня 100 статей, я хочу чтобы пользователю показывалось первые 10,а потом он нажимал на кнопку чтобы показалось еще 10
Напримере этой картинки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]